# How to properly initialize Firestore with Hot Module Reloading?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3, vite

I have a Vue 3 project with Vite, and HMR.

One issue I have is that in development mode whenever I save a file and HMR kicks in, I get the following error from Firebase:

> FirebaseError: initializeFirestore() has already been called with different options. To avoid this error, call initializeFirestore() with the same options as when it was originally called, or call getFirestore() to return the already initialized instance.

First of all, I'm not sure why or what different options it is referring to. I suspect that a Firestore instance still persists on HMR reload, but I'm still unable to use `getFirestore`.

Google searches haven't revealed anything useful regarding this particular error.

How would I go about avoiding or working around it?

```
// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = initializeFirestore(firebaseApp, {
  localCache: memoryLocalCache(),
  experimentalForceLongPolling: true,
});
```